# Show value from Google spreadsheet after form submission

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

A sports league I'm in currently stores values from a Google form in a spreadsheet as normal. There is a column that does some math with those values and gives each player a rank when they register. I want to show that rank in a modal dialog after each player registers. I can access the spreadsheet, but can't figure out how to show a dialog before it continues to the "thanks for signing up" page. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Google Forms can't run a script during that time you want - after user hitting submit and before confirmation page is shown. We can only front-load what's going to appear in the confirmation page, when a Google Form opens, with a script. Scripts can't run during the time Google Forms are being filled out either as of today.

Some options are to simply run a script that emails them after submit or to build your own Apps Script form that can look-up the calculated data you want and display it upon submit. I believe there's a Google Forms Add-on that can help with that second option.

Comment: Thanks, Bryan P. Front-loading the confirmation page works just as well!